# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'file:///D:\\image' и Microsoft Api

Tags: python, изображения, path, ос, microsoft-api

Код:

```
data = open('file:///D:\\image', 'rb')
requests.post(face_api_url,params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Нужно отправить фотографию в Microsoft Api (с локального диска Api считывать фотографию не может , по этому такой и путь странный;))

Получаю ошибку:`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'file:///D:\\image'`

**Почему** я получаю ошибку и **как** исправить код что бы ошибка пропала?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы указали неправильный путь к файлу

Попробуйте так:

```
with open('D:\\image', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
r = requests.post(face_api_url,params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
```

или так:

```
r = requests.post(face_api_url,params=params, headers=headers, data=open('D:\\image', 'rb'))
```

Из `docstring`:

```
In [22]: requests.post?
Signature: requests.post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Sends a POST request.
```

> :param `data`: (optional) Dictionary (will be form-encoded), bytes, or
>   **file-like object** to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.

Т.е. в качестве `data` можно указывать объект типа `file`

Возможно вам также придется [указать `'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'` в `headers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158257/5741205)

Answer (score 2):

У меня была такая же ошибка на windows (OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: и т.д.) при попытке открыть файл. Помогла замена слешей в пути к файлу с \ на /. Вот пример рабочего варианта:

```
f=open('d:/YandexDisk/Documents/Python/10 Экзамен/q.txt','r')
```

После этого возникла проблема с кодировкой. Решил добавлением параметра

```
encoding='utf-8'
```

Вот что получилось в итоге:

```
f=open('d:/YandexDisk/Documents/Python/10 Экзамен/q.txt','r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: А проблема была с такой строкой `'d:\YandexDisk\Documents\Python\10 Экзамен\q.txt'`?

Comment: @gil9red, да с такой. Скопировал путь из проводника Windows, а он не работает

Comment: Это потому что \ хитрая штука -- используется для задания специальных символов, типа `\n`, `\t`, `\r` и т.п. Поэтому путь у вас невалидный стал. А чтобы избежать влияния \, его нужно экранировать другим слешем: \. Есть другой способ -- использовать другой слеш -- /. Но есть еще один -- сырье строки: `r'd:\YandexDisk\Documents\Python\10 Экзамен\q.txt'`